# Guild is not defined (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot in Js and i ran into this problem where "guild" isn't defined. I've made discord.js bots before similar to this but i never ran into a error like this:

````
.setTitle(`Server infomation on ${guild.name}`)
                                  ^
ReferenceError: guild is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/.Ulur/Downloads/Discordia/index.js:15:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)```
````

And my bot code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
 .readdirSync('./commands')
 .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
 const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
// END OF CONSTANTS

const ServerInfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setColor('RANDOM')
 .setTitle(`Server infomation on ${guild.name}`)
 .setDescription(`Command executed by ${message.author.tag}`)
 .addFields(
  { name: 'Members', value: `${guild.memberCount}` },
  { name: 'Region', value: `${guild.region}` },
  { name: 'Owner', value: `${guild.owner.tag}`, inline: true },
  { name: 'Created', value: `${guild.createdAt}`, inline: true }
 );

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

 const args = message.content
  .slice(prefix.length)
  .trim()
  .split(/ +/);
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

 try {
  client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
  console.log(`Executing Command`, `${prefix}${command}`);
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
 }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: I mean.... `guild` isn't defined. What is `guild` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to get the guild object using:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("YOUR_GUILD_ID");
```

To get the guild from the message and use your code (only an example as this sends the embed every message):

```
client.on('message', message => {

  let guild = message.guild;
    const ServerInfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle(`Server infomation on ${guild.name}`)
    .setDescription(`Command executed by ${message.author.tag}`)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Members', value: `${guild.memberCount}` },
        { name: 'Region', value: `${guild.region}` },
        { name: 'Owner', value: `${guild.owner.tag}`, inline: true },
        { name: 'Created', value: `${guild.createdAt}`, inline: true },
    )

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define guild using: `var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('YOUR_GUILD_ID')`

For the message, you want to do: `var guild = message.guild`

Look the this documentation about guilds to figure out what property of the guild you want to display: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild

Hope this helps!